# bindSecure() with InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4 as dynamic address argument

Tags: dart

I'm playing around a little with [these examples](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/httpserver/#binding). I get a proper response from the server from a tablet using:

```
HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 4040)
```

Then I wanted to try the secure sockets example. For localhost it is working a expected.

```
HttpServer.bindSecure('localhost', 4047...
```

But then it will not repond to requests from other computers. So I tried this:

```
HttpServer.bindSecure(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 4047,
```

And gets compile error:

```
Breaking on exception: object of type TypeError
Unhandled exception:
type '_InternetAddress' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'address'.
#0      RawSecureServerSocket.bind (secure_server_socket.dart:182)
#1      SecureServerSocket.bind (secure_server_socket.dart:70)
#2      _HttpServer.bindSecure (http_impl.dart:2025)
#3      HttpServer.bindSecure (http.dart:179)
#4      main (file:///D:/Documents/dart/dart-tutorials-samples-master/httpserver/bin/hello_world_server_secure.dart:16:24)
#5      _startIsolate.isolateStartHandler (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:216)
#6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115)
```

I tried printing 'InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4' and got '0.0.0.0'. So I tried:

```
HttpServer.bindSecure('0.0.0.0', 4047,
```

And it  worked.

Why does 'InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4' as first argument to bindSecure fail? I don't understand the error message.

Comment: Can you please create a feature request at http://dartbug.com/new to unify the APIs

Comment: What should work as workaround is `HttpServer.bindSecure(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4.toString(), 4047,`

Comment: You'd think so, but no.

Comment: In this case you should use `InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4.address` which returns `0.0.0.0`. `InternetAddress('0.0.0.0', IP_V4).toString()` returns the string `InternetAddress('0.0.0.0', IP_V4)`.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* See comments, this was a bug/inconsistency in an old version of the Dart VM!

This looks like a bug. According to [the docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-io.HttpServer#id_bindSecure) bindSecure should take either a `String` or an `InternetAddress`, and `InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4` is even given as a sample!

> The address can either be a `String` or an `InternetAddress`. If address
>   is a `String`, bind will perform a lookup and use the first value in the
>   list. To listen on the loopback adapter, which will allow only
>   incoming connections from the local host, use the value
>   [`InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V4`] or [`InternetAddress.LOOPBACK_IP_V6`].
>   To allow for incoming connection from the network use either one of
>   the values [`InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4`] or [`InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V6`]
>   to bind to all interfaces or the IP address of a specific interface.

I've had a look through the source of these files; but can't figure out what the bug is; the code looks good at first glance :(

Comment: Ah; I did wonder whether it was an old version, but the date on the Q was recent enough I assumed it would be new!